# Where should I ask about phone hardware?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wanted to ask a question about my Samsung phone's battery. It turns out I can't ask that question on Super User, since according to their [official on-topic page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> and it is not about ... [] ... cell phones or smartphones, except insofar as they interface with your computer...

Also, you can't ask that question on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) because [their official on-topic page says](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> We cannot help with technical issues with existing hardware.

[I asked my question there](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/how-much-voltage-does-sony-ericsson-live-with-walkman-wt19-needs-for-replac) and the on-hold reason is enlightening:

> "Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting
>   hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware
>   Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase
>   hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific
>   task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on
>   Super User." – ArtOfCode

But actually as I said up there, you can't ask on Super User. I did it and got the aforementioned response.

There are:

- [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

But if my phone is a Samsung and it's not about the OS (the question is about hardware, the battery specifically, which has nothing to do with Android) then there is no option.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen hardware specific questions asked on [android.se]

Comment: Yes, I agree, there are. I'm uncorfotable asking my question about battery voltage in a site called after a OS, [but actually their policy allows my question because of the mere fact that the phone has Android in it](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So, yes, I guess that's the correct answer, I hope they receive well my question.

Comment: There are a crap-ton of questions about batteries at [android.se].